# SQL logins access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to set up a set of SQL logins (one for each developer) on a server who can have access to a given set of databases, currently the setup is as follows:

`Login 1: db_owner of databases 1, 2, 3 and 4`

`Login 2: db_owner of database 5` (this is because this login is used by someone else who shouldn't have access to the other databases).

Is there a way to add a set of new logins that would have access to all the mentioned databases without changing the existing logins? As far as I know you can't have multiple `db_owner`'s of a database.

(I know that using `sa` would do the job, but the databases are actually hosted on a third parties server with other customer's databases, so we can't use that!)

Comment: Yes you can create a new login and grant DML and DDL privileges you dont need to make login owner of database just to access it.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to see (in SSMS) all the databases that this user is (currently) db_owner of, only if the user is actually the owner of the database. I can access them via `USE [XXXX] SELECT * FROM MyTable` for example, but not in SSMS.

Comment: If login is owner of database it can see it please contact your DBA I guess you don't have sufficient rights to access that database.

Comment: Unfortunately I am the closest to a DBA currently at my place of work... hence my question here! What rights would a login need to see a given database?

Comment: You want to just see the database or you want to execute queries ?

Comment: I want to be able to access it and change anything in it within reason (Tables, Procs, Views, Schemas etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As per this question

> > want to be able to access it and change anything in it within reason (Tables, Procs, Views, Schemas etc.)

You can create a login using below acript and map it to user and then grant necessary privileges to user. Granting privilege to SQL server user is complex topic and you must read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178569.aspx) [and this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187750.aspx) for understanding it.

SQL Server, requires ALTER ANY LOGIN permission on the server or membership in the securityadmin fixed server role to create login.

```
-- Creates the login with password
CREATE LOGIN login_name 
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Password@1234';
GO

-- Creates a database user for the login created above.
CREATE USER Login_name FOR LOGIN Login_name;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'Login_name'--here login_name is user name

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'Login_name'--here login_name is user name

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'Login_name'--here login_name is user name
```

Comment: I (finally) got to try this out today, unfortunately the databases are still not visible in the SSMS UI, but I can access their tables via a `USE [DBName] SELECT * FROM MyTable` query for example.

Answer (score 0):

Granting db_owner to a user (the database level principal) is a very high level of permissions and should only be granted to database administrators.  You should probably consider only granting those permissions needed by the individuals.  Members of ddl_admin for example can make DDL changes (create/alter tables, create/alter SPs etc) to the database without being a member of the db_owner role.

That being said while only one user can be the "owner" of the database you can add as many users to the role db_owner as you would like.

```
-- Creating a login (the server level principal).
CREATE LOGIN LoginName WITH Password = 'DontUseThisPassword'

-- Making a user the owner of the database.
-- Only one login can be the owner of the database.
EXEC sp_change_db_owner 'LoginName'

-- Creating a user and adding it to the db_owner role.
-- Multiple users can be members of the db_owner role.
USE DBA
CREATE USER UserName FROM LOGIN LoginName
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','UserName'
```